# bootstrap navbar collapse won't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am making a portfolio site on codepen.io and my navbar collapse button won't work went the window size is decreased. Codepen: https://codepen.io/RayFitzgerald/full/vKgYoj/ Apologies for poorly written code. I am new.

**HTML**

```
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">

  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Ray Fitzgerald</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">button
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfollio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Social">Social</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
 </nav>
<!-- Main Body & Text Items -->
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="intro-text" id="About">
  My name is Ray Fitzgerald and I am a young Programmer and Web Developer
  </div>
  <div class="intro-text" id="Portfolio">
    Portfolio
  </div>
  <div class="intro-text" id="Social">
      Social
  </div>

 </div>
 </div> 

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.intro-text{
  font-size: 30px;

}
#About{
  height: 500px;
}
#Portfolio{
  height: 500px;
}
#Social{
  height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap navbar toggle component works only when Bootstrap Javascript is included in the code. Include bootstrap javascript file and it works like charm.

Reminder: Bootstrap JS works only if you include jQuery first.

Answer (score 2):

No bootstrap.min.js and no JQuery library found in the link provided by you.

Add JQuery library then add bootstrap.min.js it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code as it is in application this code works me at  my end

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sitename</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page sub</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```